# SpriteKit Curve physics body

Tags: curve, skphysicsbody, skshapenode

I have a SKShapeNode curve that i need to detect collision with. The problem is i can't find solution to collide only with line, it seems all the options (including detection of nodeAtPoint) treat my curve as a rectangle, or polygon thing, but not as a curved line. Is there any way to make physics body for a curved line that doesn't connect to it self?

Answer (score 0):

Was not able to find the right answer I came up to solution to use same line with reversed points so I have a loop that works well with physics.